# Request & Response XML for Spring

Tags: xml, web-services, spring, request, response

We are developing Spring Webservices to provide the service to iPad application. There is a discussion between two teams how to define the Request / Response XMLs. Architecturally our service will convert the Request XMLs into Java Beans using JAXB before it reaches Endpoint.

We are proposing that there is a separate Request / Response XMLs are required for each service like the following
1. For InsertService the XML will be 
.. 
2. For DeleteRequest the XML will be 
.. 
etc.,

But the other team is proposing the following way, 
for all the request / responses only one root node like the following
.. Insert/Delete..

Please suggest what would be right way, if it is ours how to convince them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe instead of discussing the XML, you should be discussing the schema (XSDs) for Input request and responses.

Once the schema is finalized you can generated JAXB objects from the schema itself (using xjc or maven-jaxb-plugin) and work on the webservices thereafter.

Comment: Thanks Anshu. But, from Objective C there is no XSD (I guess). If that is the case, what would be the correct way of the given two approaches?